# LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Can't find MyData Block

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming, lego-games

While going through the challenges of the Gyro Sensor Investigation I came upon the issue that I do not have the MyData Block (It's a dark blue block with a graph on it) on the coding program. Could someone include the download for this block or assist me in retrieving it?

Comment: I don't personally have an answer for you, but welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 4):

EV3 software comes in two varieties, Educational and Home. The Educational version has a few blocks that do data operations that make sense in a science class.

Both versions are downloadable from Lego for free.

I think the MyData block is actually the data logging block.  It looks like this:

[image: Data Logging Block with the Ultrasonic Sensor selected.]

To get this block for use in your programs, you would need to download and install the [Education version of Mindstorms](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3).